# Angular 2 service localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, local-storage

I'm trying to do a ToDoList in service with localstorage.

`add.component.ts`

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
    item: Item[];
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private itemService: ItemService) {
    }

    addTodo() {
        this.itemService.save();
        this.router.navigate(['./list']);
    }

   ngOnInit() {}

}
```

`item.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    private itemsUrl = 'items';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    private todos: any;
    private currentItem: any;

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private item: Item) {
        this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
        this.todos = this.currentItem;
    }

    save(): Promise<Item> {
        return this.http
            .post(this.itemsUrl, {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then((res: Response) => {

                this.todos.push({
                    id: this.item.id,
                    title: this.item.title,
                    message: this.item.message,
                    done: false
                });

                this.todos.title = '';
                this.todos.message = '';

                localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.todos))

                return this.todos;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.log('An error occured', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

`item.ts`

```
export class Item {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    message: string;
}
```

`add.component.ts`

```
<div class="container">
    <form (submit)="addTodo()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Id:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="id" class="textfield form-control" name="id">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titulo:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="title" class="textfield form-control" name="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="message" class="textfield form-control" name="message">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If I add localstorage in `add.component.ts` it works! But if a try to do it as a service I have an error : `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error Error: DI Error`

I don't know what to do. I search how to do it but I don't found an answer that would help me.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage is not an angular service. It's just a native JS object controlling the browser's localstorage. Therefor you can not inject it. If you want to have service functionality, you can wrap the native `localstorage` in an angular `LocalStorageService`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try to wrap as `LocalStorageService`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to inject `Item` into `ItemService`.  You really want to have a get function that accepts an `Item` as an argument and retrieves it from localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

As PierreDuc said, local storage is feature of the user browser. According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) it should work with all major browsers.

Because it browser feature and not part of angular it doesn't need to be injected.
More of how to use localStorage you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

If you still want to use it as an angular service I recommend you to use [this library](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage).

Comment: It should be from version 2.0 and above